# Android socket client server communication between two phones over internet fails

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, portforwarding

Can this be done? One phone is a surveillance camera and writes output to a socket. With 2 phones on the same wi-fi, this works perfectly. I have a router and have set port forwarding and have created a static address on the server phone taking video via camera. The client phone that has to view video uses mobile data. The application on the client will timeout creating socket on a public ip and port number of the server phone.

Where do I go wrong? Below is NAT settings on my router. I get my public ip from google (search my IP). Some people claim to have this working but they don't give details.

[image: Port forwarding on router]

Will this connection setting have an effect on my problem?

[image: Connection setting]

Comment: Why are you talking about your router if two phones will communicate both mobile? Please explain your setup better. All is pretty confusing.

Comment: So you have one phone that has a wifi connection with your router. On this phone runs a server app. A second phone uses mobile connection. On the latter a client app that tries to connect to the internet ip of the router. The router then forwards this request to the server phone. Indeed this should be possible.

Comment: When researching I found that a phone cannot receive socket connection without NATed router.

Comment: Unclear about which phone you talk and if it is using wifi or mobile. But the setup i described should work. It needs port forwarding of course.

Comment: I even tried socketTest V3.0. The connection times out. I'm using public IP from client and port 9191 as I set my port forwarding as above. Is portforwarding above correct? The phone above is the server socket behind router.

Comment: `I'm using public IP from client`??? Where and who is using that? Your client app runs on the phone with mobile connection. So it's public ip is irrelevant. Nobody has to know or use it.

Comment: Your client app should use the public ip of the router. And the router will forward the request to the server app on the phone connected with wifi to the router.

Comment: Thanks for your time, The latest comment is what I assumed, unfortunately the router does not or fails to direct traffic to that port.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was with the ISP restricted apn. They do not allow inbound connections.